# Why is half dose of Oxford's vaccine of covid more effective than full dose?

Tags: medicine, coronavirus, vaccination, medicinal-chemistry

I recently read in a newspaper that the half dose of the Oxford's vaccine is 90% effective while the full dose is only 62% effective.

Why is this the case ?

Comment: The true answer is nobody knows yet - even the developers of the vaccine have admitted they don't know the true reason yet. It may be the case that it is a statistical artifact of a reduced sample size in the group which was given the half dose. Either way, we need to wait at least until the paper is out until proper judgement can be made.

Comment: These explanations in nature magazine are very, very vague: https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-03326-w If it's not an artefact of statistics, they say it could be because the larger dose caused the body to attack the associated adenovirus complex on which the vaccine is delivered into the body and blunt the immune reaction to the covid-19 complex,

Comment: There are also very recent news articles about manufacturing errors causing the wrong dosage, e.g. https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2020-11-26/astra-faces-more-vaccine-questions-after-manufacturing-error  So perhaps the vials marked "half dose" were really full doses?  So the "answer" is that nobody knows yet.